# changing value of a textview while change in other textview by multiplying

Tags: android, parsing, valuechangelistener

Here I am getting parsed data from a URL and now I am trying to change the value of parse data to users only dynamically on an text view and my code is

```
public class Main extends ListActivity {

    EditText resultTxt;

    public double C_webuserDouble;
    public double C_cashDouble;
    public double C_transferDouble;

    public double S_webuserDouble;
    public double S_cashDouble;
    public double S_transferDouble;

    TextView cashTxtView;
    TextView webuserTxtView;
    TextView transferTxtView;
    TextView S_cashTxtView;
    TextView S_webuserTxtView;
    TextView S_transferTxtView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);
        cashTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cashTxtView);
        webuserTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.webuserTxtView);
        transferTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.transferTxtView);

        S_cashTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.S_cashTxtView);
        S_webuserTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.S_webuserTxtView);
        S_transferTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.S_transferTxtView);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        JSONObject json = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL("http://ldsclient.com/ftp/strtojson.php");

        try {

            JSONArray netfoxlimited = json.getJSONArray("netfoxlimited");

            for (inti = 0; i < netfoxlimited.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                JSONObject e = netfoxlimited.getJSONObject(i);

                map.put("date", e.getString("date"));
                map.put("c_web", e.getString("c_web"));
                map.put("c_bank", e.getString("c_bank"));
                map.put("c_cash", e.getString("c_cash"));
                map.put("s_web", e.getString("s_web"));
                map.put("s_bank", e.getString("s_bank"));
                map.put("s_cash", e.getString("s_cash"));
                mylist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.main,
                new String[] { "date", "c_web", "c_bank", "c_cash", "s_web",
                        "s_bank", "s_cash", }, new int[] { R.id.item_title,
                        R.id.webuserTxtView, R.id.transferTxtView,
                        R.id.cashTxtView, R.id.S_webuserTxtView,
                        R.id.S_transferTxtView, R.id.S_cashTxtView });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        final ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv
                        .getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(Main.this,
                        "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        resultTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        resultTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                resultTxt.setText("");
            }
        });
        resultTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String text;
                text = resultTxt.getText().toString();
                if (resultTxt.getText().length() > 5) {
                    calculateSum(C_webuserDouble, C_cashDouble,
                            C_transferDouble);
                    calculateSunrise(S_webuserDouble, S_cashDouble,
                            S_transferDouble);
                } else {

                }
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
    }

    private void calculateSum(Double webuserDouble, Double cashDouble,
            Double transferDouble) {

        String Qty;
        Qty = resultTxt.getText().toString();

        if (Qty.length() > 0) {
            double QtyValue = Double.parseDouble(Qty);
            double cashResult;
            double webuserResult;
            double transferResult;

            cashResult = cashDouble * QtyValue;
            webuserResult = webuserDouble * QtyValue;
            transferResult = transferDouble * QtyValue;

            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            String cashResultStr = df.format(cashResult);
            String webuserResultStr = df.format(webuserResult);
            String transferResultStr = df.format(transferResult);

            cashTxtView.setText(String.valueOf(cashResultStr));
            webuserTxtView.setText(String.valueOf(webuserResultStr));
            transferTxtView.setText(String.valueOf(transferResultStr));

            // cashTxtView.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new
            // DecimalDigitsInputFilter(2)});

        }

        if (Qty.length() == 0) {
            cashTxtView.setText(String.valueOf(cashDouble));
            webuserTxtView.setText(String.valueOf(webuserDouble));
            transferTxtView.setText(String.valueOf(transferDouble));

        }

    }

    private void calculateSunrise(Double webuserDouble, Double cashDouble,
            Double transferDouble) {

        String Qty;
        Qty = resultTxt.getText().toString();

        if (Qty.length() > 0) {
            double QtyValue = Double.parseDouble(Qty);
            double cashResult;
            double webuserResult;
            double transferResult;

            cashResult = cashDouble * QtyValue;
            webuserResult = webuserDouble * QtyValue;
            transferResult = transferDouble * QtyValue;

            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            String cashResultStr = df.format(cashResult);
            String webuserResultStr = df.format(webuserResult);
            String transferResultStr = df.format(transferResult);

            S_cashTxtView.setText(String.valueOf(cashResultStr));
            S_webuserTxtView.setText(String.valueOf(webuserResultStr));
            S_transferTxtView.setText(String.valueOf(transferResultStr));
        }

        if (Qty.length() == 0) {
            S_cashTxtView.setText(String.valueOf(cashDouble));
            S_webuserTxtView.setText(String.valueOf(webuserDouble));
            S_transferTxtView.setText(String.valueOf(transferDouble));

        }

    }
}
```

and I am getting following error on logcat

```
08-28 15:04:12.839: E/AndroidRuntime(584): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-28 15:04:12.848: E/AndroidRuntime(584): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mokshya.jsontutorialhos.xmltest/com.mokshya.jsontutorial.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-28 15:04:12.848: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2401)
08-28 15:04:12.848: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
08-28 15:04:12.848: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
08-28 15:04:12.848: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
08-28 15:04:12.848: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-28 15:04:12.848: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-28 15:04:12.848: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
08-28 15:04:12.848: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-28 15:04:12.848: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-28 15:04:12.848: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
08-28 15:04:12.848: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
08-28 15:04:12.848: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-28 15:04:12.848: E/AndroidRuntime(584): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-28 15:04:12.848: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at com.mokshya.jsontutorial.Main.onCreate(Main.java:111)
08-28 15:04:12.848: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
08-28 15:04:12.848: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
```

Comment: post the rest of logcat output. it will show you where the null point occur.

Comment: @Cdr. Powell how do you edit it i tried lot but can't fix it.thanx

Comment: @sur007 the problem is here "resultTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);" you are getting null for your EditText resultTxt, check it once

Comment: Just placed 4 spaces in front of every row. Dunno if an apostrophe works as well but I'm lazy and sleepy so this was adequate to me.

Comment: What code do you have on line 111 in your main class?

Comment: resultTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { t is the 111 code

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your layout file contains a ListView with id=list. This is a must for ListActivity.

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="#00FF00"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>
```

Click [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) for reference.

Check whether getListView() is returning null or not before setting setListAdapter in onCreateView.

Comment: then wat is the solution?ny idea??

Comment: something is null inside oncreateview, you need to find it out for fixing. Try running the application in debug mode and go through each line of oncreate view by pressing F6